# Getting PUT routes to work in Angular

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angular, mean-stack, put

I'm seeking some wisdom from the Angular community.  I am working on a simple project using the MEAN stack.  I have set up my back-end api and everything is working as expected.  Using Postman, I observe expected behavior for both a GET and PUT routes to retrieve/update a single value - a high score - which is saved in it's own document in its own collection in a MongoDB.  So far so good.

Where things go off track is when trying to access the PUT api endpoint from within Angular. Accessing the GET endpoint is no problem, and retrieving and displaying data works smoothly.  However, after considerable reading and searching, I am stll unable to properly access the PUT endpoint and update the high score data when that event is triggered by gameplay. Below are the snippets of code that I believe to be relevant for reference.

**BACK-END CODE:**

*SCHEMA:*

```
const _scoreSchema = {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    value: { type: Number, "default": 0 }
};
```

*ROUTES:*

```
router
    .route('/api/score/:highScore')
    .put(scoreController.setHighScore);
```

*CONTROLLER:*

```
static setHighScore(req, res) {
    scoreDAO
        .setHighScore(req.params.highScore)
        .then(highScore => res.status(200).json(highScore))
        .catch(error => res.status(400).json(error));
}
```

*DAO:*

```
scoreSchema.statics.setHighScore = (value) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    score
            .findOneAndUpdate(
                {"name": "highScore"},
                {$set: {"value": value} }
            )
            .exec(function(err, response) {
                err ? reject(err)
                : resolve(response);
            });
  });
}
```

**ANGULAR CODE:**

*CONTROLLER:*

```
private _updateHighScore(newHighScore): void {
    console.log('score to be updated to:', newHighScore)
    this._gameService
        .updateHighScore(newHighScore);
}
```

*SERVICE:*

```
updateHighScore(newHighScore: Number): Observable<any>  {
    console.log(newHighScore);

    let url = '/api/score/' + newHighScore;
    let _scoreStringified = JSON.stringify({value: newHighScore});

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

    return this._http
                         .put(url , _scoreStringified, {headers})
                         .map((r) => r.json());
}
```

Note that the console.log(newHighScore) in the last block of code above correctly prints the value of the new high score to be updated, it's just not being written to the database.

**The conceptual question with PUT routes in angular is this: If the api is already set up such that it receives all the information it needs to successfully update the database (via the route param) why is it required to supply all of this information again in the Angular .put() function?**  It seems like reinventing the wheel and not really utilizing the robust api endpoint that was already created.  Said differently, before digging into the docs, I naively was expecting something like .put(url) to be all that was required to call the api, so what is the missing link in my logic?

Thanks!

Comment: I tried to understand your reasoning and I think what you suspected is the params from the route to be used in the HTTP put request automatically. However, these params are different, one is used in the router and another for the Http service which is completely separate. I can elaborate more if this is your issue.

Comment: @mygeea, I don't think the route params should be used in the HTTP request automatically, but they are captured and passed into a function that performs the PUT request.  That's the server side routing process as I understand it. Just to clarify, were you talking about server side only (as I understood your response to be), or were you referring to Angular? If your answer was talking about client side routes/params, please do elaborate. Thanks.